# Adding motion blur to a background behind glass

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I would like to add motion blur to the background of my render, the problem is that I have some glass in front of the background and I can't find a way to preserve the glass and the roughness map on top of it without blurring that too. Do I have to do 2 renders? If that's the case how can I combine them together using the blender compositor? Do I have to composite on another program?

[image]

The image shows the glass before the background, by the way, the background is an HDRI

Comment: If you’re willing to use compositing, your problem is mostly solved. You won’t have to use an external compositor I’m sure.

Comment: Yeah I am willing to use compositing my problem is how i get there with compositing ahahahahah